# Is this an android searchView Bug?

Tags: android

SearchView does not seem to be working properly in a fragment. When I do a simple text search it is working just fine, but when you tap the audio icon and you input something, the searchview is redirecting to main fragment.

```
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(@NonNull Menu menu, @NonNull MenuInflater inflater) {
    // super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
    this.menu = menu;
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.options_menu, menu);

    SearchManager searchManager =
            (SearchManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
    SearchView searchView =
            (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.mainSearch).getActionView();
    searchView.setSearchableInfo(
            searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getActivity().getComponentName()));
    searchView.setIconifiedByDefault(false);

    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(this);
}
```

Is there a similar method like setOnQueryTextListener but for mic icon?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In onOptionsItemSelected method:

```
case R.id.menuVoiceRecog:
                Intent intent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
                intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL,
                        RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
                intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_PROMPT, "Voice recognition Demo...");
                startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE);

            break;
```

Then...

```
static final int REQUEST_CODE=1;
```

In onActivityResult

```
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
    {
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK)
        {
            // Populate the wordsList with the String values the recognition engine thought it heard
            ArrayList<String> matches = data.getStringArrayListExtra(
                    RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);

            showToast(matches.get(0));
            edWords.setText(edWords.getText().toString().trim()+" "+matches.get(0));
        }
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
```

The intent returns matching result as an array with tag EXTRA_RESULTS. Where 0 the element is best match, 1st element is second best match and so on.  Even if you have spoken several words, entire recognition will be available as a single string as first String only. So we catch this string and append in our editText.

Comment: Where is onOptionSelection  ? are you talking about onOptionsItemSelected  or maybe onCreateOptionsMenu ?

Comment: The case that I have mentioned must be inside the onOptionsItemSelected. I'v edited the answer.

Comment: onOptionsItemSelected is not being called unless I click it from the top bar. This is not a solution, this is a hack(that does not working anyway). So do you have any ideea how to report a bug to Google? As far as I see nobody knows how to make this work ....

Comment: i give up on using this. now I'm using a simple text input that doing the same thing without so many problems ....

Comment: According to your question that was: "Is there a similar method like setOnQueryTextListener but for mic icon?" the above solution should work. And onOptionsItemSelected only responds when an item. in the action bar is selected or clicked.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this is an Android Bug. The only answer I got it was not working and it was a hack anyway, so this is an #AndroidBug